# ignoring NA values in a loop function for outlier detection

Tags: function, loops, multiple-columns, na

I am using a function to identify outliers in all columns of my df at the same time (36 variables), but it only returns that is not possible to calculate, because are present NA values. Below the code

```
  # create detect outlier function
outlier <- function(x) {
  # calculate first quantile
  Quantile1 <- quantile(x, probs=.25)
  # calculate third quantile
  Quantile3 <- quantile(x, probs=.75)
  # calculate inter quartile range
  IQR = Quantile3-Quantile1
  # return true or false
  x > Quantile3 + (IQR*1.5) | x < Quantile1 - (IQR*1.5)
  
}

# create remove outlier function
remove_outlier <- function(pheno_bw,
                            columns=names(pheno_bw)) {
  # for loop to traverse in columns vector
  for (col in columns) {
    # remove observation if it satisfies outlier function
    pheno_bw < - pheno_bw[!outlier(pheno_bw[[col]]), ]
  }
  # return dataframe
  print("outliers")
  print(pheno_bw1)
}

remove_outlier(pheno_BW_stat, c('BW_M', 'BW_Pa'))
```

But returns this

```
Error in quantile.default(x, probs = 0.25) :
```

missing values ​​and NaN are not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

i tried put na.rm=TRUE

But dont work, tanks you

Comment: couldn't you wrap that function in an IF statement to only execute if it's valid?

Comment: some example @sous2817 please

Comment: I'm a C# / VBA guy.  What language is this, R?  If so, something like this may get you started: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/control-structures-in-r-using-loops-and-if-else-statements/